# Restarting service pmta dosn't work

Tags: email-server, centos6, sendmail

Hello i have problem when i strat Pmta  this is message i get when i debug pmta
Thank you

Error initializing thread: Error binding socket to 63.141.251.74:2500, status = EADDRINUSE

Edit:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State PID/Program name 

tcp 0 0 63.141.251.74:22 196.75.148.235:59442 ESTABLISHED 2836/sshd 
tcp 0 0 63.141.251.75:22 182.100.67.4:35358 ESTABLISHED 7761/sshd 
tcp 0 0 63.141.251.74:22 182.100.67.4:21956 ESTABLISHED 7763/sshd 
tcp 0 272 63.141.251.74:22 196.75.148.235:59320 ESTABLISHED 2716/sshd
```

Comment: Something is running on port 2500. Check it with `netstat -ntp` | grep 2500`.

Comment: Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 63.141.251.74:22            196.75.148.235:59442        ESTABLISHED 2836/sshd
tcp        0      0 63.141.251.74:22            182.100.67.4:51758          ESTABLISHED 7109/sshd
tcp        0    272 63.141.251.74:22            196.75.148.235:59320        ESTABLISHED 2716/sshd
tcp        0      0 63.141.251.75:22            182.100.67.4:14024          ESTABLISHED 7111/sshd

Comment: hello sir thank you for the answer when i use  netstat -ntp this is the out put


Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 63.141.251.74:22            196.75.148.235:59442        ESTABLISHED 2836/sshd
tcp        0      0 63.141.251.75:22            182.100.67.4:35358          ESTABLISHED 7761/sshd
tcp        0      0 63.141.251.74:22            182.100.67.4:21956          ESTABLISHED 7763/sshd
tcp        0    272 63.141.251.74:22            196.75.148.235:59320        ESTABLISHED 2716/sshd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that something is already listening on 2500.

Check with

```
netstat -tlpn
```

If there is something listening on port 2500, you can kill it and then try starting Pmta

Comment: can you paste the output here, please?

Comment: this is the result with netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 63.141.251.74:22            196.75.148.235:59442        ESTABLISHED 2836/sshd
tcp        0      0 63.141.251.75:22            182.100.67.4:35358          ESTABLISHED 7761/sshd
tcp        0      0 63.141.251.74:22            182.100.67.4:21956          ESTABLISHED 7763/sshd
tcp        0    272 63.141.251.74:22            196.75.148.235:59320        ESTABLISHED 2716/sshd

Comment: this is the result @Olive.b

Comment: on that output I can only see the established connections not what the server is listening to. Can you check with netstat -tulpn | grep 2500

Comment: i have execute the commande that you gave it to  me netstat -tlpn | grep 2500  but nothing is shown

Comment: i have execute the commande that you gave it to  me netstat -tlpn | grep 2500  but nothing is shown

Comment: but when i execute  netstat -tulpn | grep 25 this is the result
___________________________________________________



[root@server Port25-Accounter-1.2]# netstat -tulpn | grep 25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      31627/master
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      31627/master

Comment: strange can you add the u, meaning netstat -tulpn

Comment: this is 25 not 2500

Comment: Can you try with lsof -i:2500

Comment: No sir doesnt work is it possible that the provider is disabling port 25

Comment: No sir doesnt work is it possible that the provider is disabling port 25 @Olive.b

Comment: You are running the service start with root account or sudo right?

Comment: yes sir with root acount @Olive.b

Comment: I am not sure about that, I am not familiar with pmta. I would also check the logs  /var/log/pmta/log and also run   /usr/sbin/pmtad –debug and I also would check with this blog http://www.rekblog.com/how-to-setup-powermta/ if I could find something that might be relevant. There are some smtp-directives for port 25 and 2500.